# gitlab slack notifications on global level

Tags: gitlab, slack

It is possible to configure gitlab to notify about actions (push, merge, tags, etc.) on project level. Now, I do not want to configure that for every project separately as there could be a large number of projects with similar settings. Is it possible to do this on a global level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Webhook is first a project-level setting](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/user/project/integrations/webhooks.md), so it is not available for groups.

There is a [ticket pending](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/1354) (January 2017) for Webhook group API, but only for EE (Enterprise Edition), not CE (Community Edition)